# Finding the conditional expectation, a box with $6$ coins

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

A box contain $6$ coins, $3$ coins are regular, in two coins there are   $"T"$ in both sides, and in one coin there is $"H"$ in both sides, we takig randomly one coin and throwing it $100$ times.

> find the expectation value of the number of throwing that we got $"T"$

My try:

Let us denote $A_1$ the incident that we got a regular coin

$A_2$ the incident that we got the coin with $"T"$ in both sides

$A_3$ the incident that we got the coin with $"H"$ in both sides

$$E[X]=E[X|A_1]P(A_1)+E[X|A_2]P(A_2)+E[X|A_3]P(A_3)\\\frac 1 2E[X|A_1]\cdot \frac 1 3E[X|A_2]\cdot\frac 1 6\cdot E[X|A_3]$$

> I'm stuck about calculating $E[X|A_i]$ for $1\leq i\leq 3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does a regular coin has "H" on one side and "T" on the other?

If so, than $E(X|A_1)= 50$

Comment: ..Yes, it is...

Comment: We throw an even coin 100 times. Expected number of "T" s is just 50. For a "T"-coin it should be 100 (basically, every trial is a success) and for an "E"-coin it is just zero.

Comment: Can you explain why please? (+1)

Comment: Sure. Since you regard the specific case, when normal coin was already chosen, you just need to calculate mathematical expectatiin of a number of tails for 100 trials for one coin, i.e. $E(100) = \sum_{1}^{100} P_T \dot 1$, where $P_T$ is a probability of tails.